# how to remove element by click using jquery

Tags: jquery, element

I want to remove or add `<p>` tags after, or before, `<hr>`; but when I click onto the `<hr>` and want to delete just one `<hr>` jQuery deletes two.

Also, when I click on the add button, I want to just add one `<p>` tag, but jQuery added two.

How can I fix this?

```js
$("hr").each(function () 
{
    var seatID = $(this);

    $(document).on('click', "hr", function()
    {
        const delete2 = document.querySelector('.del_i');
        const after = document.querySelector('.add_b');
        const before = document.querySelector('.add_u');
        var selector = $(this);
        $(".tools_editor").show();
        var offset = $(this).offset();
        $('.tools_editor').css(
            {position: 'absolute', 
             top: (offset.top + 60)+'px', 
             left: $( window ).width() / 2 + 'px'
            });
            
        delete2.addEventListener('click', () => {
            selector.remove();
            $(".tools_editor").hide();
        })
        after.addEventListener('click', () => {
            selector.after("<p>add bottom p</p>");
            $(".tools_editor").hide();
             
        })
        before.addEventListener('click', () => 
        {
            selector.before("<p>add top p</p>");
            $(".tools_editor").hide();
        })
    });
});
```

```css
hr:before {
    font-size: 18px;
    font-family: tahoma;
    letter-spacing: .7rem;
    content: "......";
    display: block;
    margin: 0 auto;
    color: #858585;
    padding: 15px 0;
}
hr::after {
    position: absolute;
    content: '';
    z-index: 2;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    cursor: pointer;
    display: block;
    background: rgba(0,0,0,0);
}
hr {
    position: relative;
}
.tools_editor {
    box-shadow: -2px 1px 3px 0 rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.5);
    padding: 10px;
    background: #fff;
    z-index: 1;
    border-radius: 6px;
}

.tools_editor:before,
.tools_editor:after {
    position:absolute;
    content:"";
}
.tools_editor:after {
    border:12px solid transparent;
}
.tools_editor:before {
    border:10px solid transparent;
}

.tools_editor:after {
    left:50%;
    margin-left:-6px;
    top:-24px;
    border-bottom-color:rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.1)
}
.tools_editor:before {
    left:50%;
    margin-left:-4px;
    top:-20px;
    border-bottom-color:#fff;
    z-index:1;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<hr>
<p>test 1</p>
<p>test 2</p>
<hr>


<div style="display:none;" class="tools_editor dis_n">
<i class="del_i" style="cosur:pointer:padding:5px;">delete</i> | <i class="add_b" style="cosur:pointer:padding:5px;">add bottom</i> | <i class="add_u">add top</i>
</div>
```

Comment: That's because you are nesting an event handler inside the `.each()` function. That's an anti-pattern. For every `<hr>` element you're creating a click event handler on the document, and that's why it fires twice: since you've got two elements on the page.

Comment: yes i know. but i need just once element for deletes or... because sometime i have so musch tags hr.